# Adding users to roles from VB script component, users do not get added

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, ssas

I have an SSIS dtsx file, which has a VB script component. Inside it, I'm trying to add users to role in my tabular database, but even though the script doesn't exit because of any errors, users do not show up in the role membership list.

I tried to skip as much unnecessary code as possible, so please comment if you think I skipped something that you think is important

```vb
Dim amoServer As New AMO.Server
Dim amoDatabase As New AMO.Database
Dim amoRole As New AMO.ModelRole
Dim amoRoleMember As New AMO.WindowsModelRoleMember

amoServer.Connect(serverName)
amoDatabase = amoServer.Databases.FindByName(dbName)
amoRole = amoDatabase.Model.Roles.Find(Dts.Variables("SecurityGroupName").Value.ToString)

Dim login As String, action As String
login = "XXX\test001"
action = "Granted"

RM = New AMO.WindowsModelRoleMember()
RM.MemberName = login

Try
    If (action = "Granted") Then
        amoRole.Members.Add(RM)
        amoDatabase.Update()
    End If
Catch 
    .... not important in this case
```

Comment: SSIS scripting is VB.NET; there's no `Try...Catch` in VBA.

Comment: Debugging SSIS script components is a bit of a PITA. Sprinkle some logging in key places, validate that your `amoDatabase` connection is up, log any exceptions - are you getting any exception? Does the `Catch` block set the script component to return a failure?

Comment: Not that I have any experience specifically with SSIS scripts, but doesn't one grant the role to the user, not the user to the role.  Just curious.

Comment: The T-SQL equivalent would be something like `ALTER SERVER ROLE [role] ADD MEMBER [domain\user]` so the operation does make logical sense here I think.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I could debug the script component locally, and it seemed that all connections opened up properly. No exception was thrown. The fact that nothing changes even though no errors are thrown is what seems strange.